Do you get common mode noise at the receiver if the receiver side has common impedance to ground, but not the transmitter side?
Balanced lines are when two conductors have a common impedance along the entire length of the conductors. This helps ensure that noise induces equal voltage spikes as seen by the differential receiver enabling common mode noise that can be rejected.
My question concerns when a single-ended driver is connected to a differential receiver. In this case, the receiver side offers common impedance to ground. However, the driver side does not offer common impedance.
Literature suggests that this will ruin the benefits of common mode noise rejection. But why? If EMI induces the same current across each conductor and the impedance as seen by the receiver is common for each input.. wouldn't the same voltage be induced on each input of the receiver?
Looking for help as to why connecting a single-end input connection to a differential receiver would ruin the benefits of common mode noise rejection.

Noise rejection properties of balanced/differential transmission come from:

Equal impedance of both positive and negative signals in the differential pair turn incoming EMI into common mode signal

Common mode rejection in the receiver.

Cable shield not being used as a voltage reference, allowing currents to flow in it without adding voltage drop to the signal



On top, a differential transmitter is coupled to a differential receiver via a differential pair, each signal in the pair having equal source impedance.
On the bottom, the transmitter is single ended, but a source resistor has been added to the source ground. The result is more or less the same.
In the second case, the output impedance of the driver will not be zero and will vary with frequency, so balance is not as good. Also, signal amplitude is halved, so signal to noise ratio is also halved. But the noise rejection properties of the receiver still work.
If the resistor in the ground line is removed, then it is no longer balanced transmission, and the receiver is no longer able to reject noise picked up by the differential pair. But it is still able to reject potential difference between its own ground and the transmitter ground. So this has some of the advantages of "true" differential transmission, but not all.

If the line is not differential, and the shield is used as 0V reference, then current from ground loops may flow into it and add voltage drop on top of the signal. In this case, even though a differential receiver chip is used, this has no advantage compared to single ended transmission.

I've made my own diagram (https://imgur.com/a/xAFA5rR) where a purely resistive single-ended transmitted is attached to a differential receiver. Assuming EMI noise injection (In) is common to each conductor, that should result in the same voltage spike scene by the receiver due to Ohm's Law. Correct? Thus we'll have common mode noise at the receiver?
Am I make any incorrect assumption in my diagram?

The 0V wire is connected directly to ground at the source, whereas the other wire has a resistor to set source impedance. Even if both termination resistors at the receiver end are the same, since the source impedances are different, the line is not balanced. So injected EMI will be different in each conductor, it will not be common mode, so it will not be rejected.

that's the part that confuses me. My interpretation is that EMI would induce the same current regardless of impedance. The induced current is a response to resisting change in magnetic flux. But it sounds like the assumption in my diagram that the noise current In is the same regardless of impedance is not correct. Why is that?

Even if it does induce the same current, if the impedance is different, these two identical currents turn into different voltages on the two lines. V=RI
